# Select required 'select box' with empty value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried using, the following code, with no success:
**jQuery:**

```
if($('select[required][value=""]').length>0){
    alert('w0t m8');   
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<select required="required">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/xemucr7q/

Comment: why not change you condition like `$('select[required]').val() == ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple selects on page then:

```
$('select[required]').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).val()){
        alert('what');
    }
});
```

If you want to check on change:

```
$('select[required]').on('change', function(){
     if(!$(this).val()){
         alert('what');
     }
});
```

**Question**: Do you know why $('select[required][value=""]').length doesn't return the length of the empty required selects?

**Answer**: Try the following

```
alert($("select[required]").find(":selected").not('[value]').length)
```

OR maybe this suits better:

```
alert($("select[required]").find(":selected[value='']").length)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xemucr7q/1/)

Comment: Do you know why $('select[required][value=""]').length doesn't return the length of the empty required selects? Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/vk575sf2/3

Comment: Try this `alert($("select[required]").find(":selected").not('[value]').length)`

Answer (score 1):

The below code will work for the given html

```
$('select[required]').on('change', function() {
    if(!$(this).val()){
        alert('w0t m8');   
    }
});
```

Comment: `if(!$('select[required]').val())` should we not $(this) in this case?

Comment: even `$(this).val()` works, as we are listening to event on the same element. Just `$(this)` will not work, as it will refer to select element instead of its value.

Comment: ya that is what a meant.. but there is a difference when using $(this) as opposed to the selector when we have multiple selects on the page. Specially when you are listening for an event fired by a particular element i strongly recommend that you use $(this)

Comment: Yeah.. its better to use this. But, instead if you have multiple selects, its better to give an id & listen to events on that id instead of listening to change of each and every element. Thanks for the feedback, updated the answer with $(this).

Comment: FYI, even if you dont have multiple selects/elements even then using $(this) will result in better performance. Thanks for updating the answer and avoiding a potential cause of error :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the if statement.use:

```
if($('select[required][value=""]').length){
   alert('w0t m8');   
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vk575sf2/)**

For making it work on dropdown change event:

```
$('select[required]').change(function(){
if($('select[required][value=""]').length){
  alert('w0t m8');   
}}).change();
```

Comment: Your example is not selecting only empty ones.

Comment: It shouldn't be alerting when an option is selected but it is: http://jsfiddle.net/wouguh8t/1/.

Comment: Just remove the not keyword. See the updated answer.Do you also want this to work when dropdown value is changed??

Comment: `if(!$('select[required]').val())` should we not $(this) in this case? What if there are multiple selects on page?

Comment: I don't know why it isn't counting the length right, check:http://jsfiddle.net/vk575sf2/3/, it says the length is 0 while it's 2.